# Bootstrap nav pills - 'active' class doesn't work in opened modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following code for `nav-pills` component:

```
  <ul id="steps" class="nav nav-pills form-steps">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#options"></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#payments"></a></li>
  </ul>
```

This is how the look of active `a` is made (basically it's just a circle filled with special color):

```
.form-steps > li.active > a {
    background-color: #931f2a;
}
```

And here's code for a regular `a`:

```
.promoter-form-steps > li > a {
    border: 2px solid #931f2at;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

I suppose that by adding `.active` class to corresponding `li` element makes `a` element filled with color, but it doesn't when I open modal where this component is placed for the fist time. When I open modal for the second time after I click on another link, I see correct behavior, i.e `.active` class is filled with color. It's an SPA and I have another `nav-pills` like this with exact markup and it works just fine and I don't quite understand why this behavior doesn't work on second `nav-pills`. I double checked that class names and ids don't repeat each others and I am sure that no custom js was involved into this.
Can you please give me a direction to inspect what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the recommended format as determined by Twitter Docs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your list tags need to have a class of nav-item and your anchors need a class of nav-link before it can use the active class

Comment: Hello Jacob, thanks for investing your time into solving my issue. Unfortunately your way didn't work for me. I updated my question a little bit to give more details.